# Couldn't find User without an ID when calling method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a modal, with a form inside it. However I get the classic error when I try to submit:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for add_email_users_path, url: { action: 'add_email', controller: 'users' } do |f| %>
 <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address', class: 'input-lg form-control' %>
 <%= f.button 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-success', 'data-disable-with' => "Saving <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy] do
  post 'add_email', on: :collection
end
```

User_controller:

```
def add_email
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(setup_params)
    redirect_to campaigns_path, notice: 'Thank you for adding your email!'
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Unable to save your email'
  end
end
```

Comment: add_email_users_path(@user)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for add_email_users_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address', class: 'input-lg form-control' %>
  <%= f.button 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-success', 'data-disable-with' => "Saving <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

and your route:

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy] do
  post 'add_email', on: :member
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong path method in your form_for, it should be:

`add_email_user_path(@user)`

And your route should be for member not collection:

`post 'add_email', on: :member`

Here is what your stuff should look like:

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for add_email_user_path(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address', class: 'input-lg form-control' %>
 <%= f.button 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-success', 'data-disable-with' => "Saving <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy] do
  post :add_email, on: :member
end
```

Take special note of the change to the form_for call.

Comment: gives me: No route matches {:action=>"add_email", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Can you post the result for `rake routes | grep user`?

Comment: add_email_user POST   /users/:id/add_email(.:format)           users#add_email
           users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               users#show
                 PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                users#update

Comment: Yeah, and you don't need the ":url => ..." when you are already supplying the path in the first param.

Comment: still don't work, as I tried to specify in my answer it might be due to the location. the code itself is in a partial in the application.html and is ran if current_user && current_user.email.nil? thus it can be ran in any controller. Is this relevant?

Comment: If you add this before the form does it output an id?

`<%= puts @user.id %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73881/discussion-between-sja-and-ken-stipek).

Answer (score 0):

It can't be a `collection` method as it is looking for specific `id` define it as a `member` method

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy] do    
   member do
       post :add_email
   end
end
```

In form

```
<%= form_for add_email_user_path(@user), method: :post do |f| %>
```

You can refer to this [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to understand `member` and `collection` methods

Comment: Leaves me with: param is missing or the value is empty: campaign